# Enemy following player in XNA and stop within 20 pixels

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, xna-4.0, 2d-games

I'm trying to get my enemies to follow the player and stop within 20 pixels, I have tried a number of algorithms including the Vector2.Lerp(); method to try and fix this but it keeps breaking the build. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The code is below.

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (this.IsAlive)
    {
        float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        double distanceToPlayer = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Level.Player.Position.X - this.Position.X, 2) + Math.Pow(Level.Player.Position.Y - this.Position.Y, 2));

        // Calculate tile position based on the side we are walking towards.
        float posX = Position.X + localBounds.Width / 2 * (int)direction;
        int tileX = (int)Math.Floor(posX / Tile.Width) - (int)direction;
        int tileY = (int)Math.Floor(Position.Y / Tile.Height);

        if (waitTime > 0)
        {
            // Wait for some amount of time.
            waitTime = Math.Max(0.0f, waitTime - (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds);
            if (waitTime <= 0.0f)
            {
                // Then turn around.
                direction = (FaceDirection)(-(int)direction);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If we are about to run into a wall or off a cliff, start waiting.
            if (Level.GetCollision(tileX + (int)direction, tileY - 1) == TileCollision.Impassable || Level.GetCollision(tileX + (int)direction, tileY) == TileCollision.Passable) //is the enemy is close and is not attacking, attack and turn!
            {
                waitTime = MaxWaitTime;
            }
            else
            {
                // Move in the current direction.
                Vector2 velocity = new Vector2((int)direction * MoveSpeed * elapsed, 0.0f);
                position = position + velocity;
            }
        }
        dtAttack += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;
        AttackPlayer();
    }
    else
    {
        dt += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;
        if (dt.TotalSeconds > (sprite.Animation.FrameCount * sprite.Animation.FrameTime))
            this.Remove = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: To try and fix.. What? Also, To get distance between to positions you can just do `Vector2.Distance`. Where ever you want it to stop, add if (distance < 20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be 20 pixels on the screen? Seems strange.
You could try to calculate the euclidean distance between the player and the enemy, using the `Vector2.Distance` method. If the distance is 20 or lower, stop the enemy. If not, keep following the player.